# how do i setup the run time environment of microsoft visual fox pro on windows 7?

Tags: visual-foxpro

how do i setup the run time environment of microsoft visual fox pro on windows 7 ?
 I tried a lot after google the problem but still facing the same problem that is "Cannot find the runtime library of mirosoft visual foxpro". 
Edit: 
I am trying to install a standalone software that is made in foxpro in my laptop. And i never use foxpro so i don't know about it's runtime library or it's environment. So How do i setup it ? So that i can use that software. It is always showing me "Cannot find the runtime library of mirosoft visual foxpro"

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do, or what you have tried.

Comment: Now i explain it clearly @jdv. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple. Generally just having the 3 dlls in the same folder where your exe is sufficient (VFP9t.dll, VFP9r.dll and VFP9ENU.dll). These files are normally located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VFP" folder (and VFP9ENU.dll is the English resource file, there are others).

Or you might go to Christof's site to download:
[VFP runtime files](http://www.foxpert.com/download/runtime.html)

Comment: Assuming VFP 9. They could be VFP8t.dll or VFP7.dll or the like according to the exact version.

Comment: Yes I assumed 9 at this time :) I also assumed it was easy enough to simply replace 9 with 8,7 or even 6.

Comment: @CetinBasoz does visual foxpro work on windows 10? i am looking to open .mkt files.

Comment: @bespectacled, VFP does work on windows 10, but I don't know what is a .mkt file. Please ask your questions in a new message rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar issues with Windows 10 recently.
Copying all the below dll's into the startup-directory of the FoxPro-application made it run smoothly.
(dwintl.dll, filer.dll, foxisapi.dll, gdiplus.dll, htmllite.dll, msvcr71.dll, vfp9chs.dll, vfp9cht.dll, vfp9enu.dll, vfp9kor.dll, vfp9r.dll, VFP9RENU.DLL)